# What is a "barrier" in Qiskit circuits?

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, ibm-q-experience

I just started studying IBM Qiskit, and cannot find details about the barrier method on the QuantumCircuit class. It is shown in the circuit drawing, but I never heard about it after reading quantum computing text books. Is it a unitary gate? If so, how is it defined? Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You won't find the barrier in quantum computing textbooks because it isn't a standard primitive of quantum information theory like unitary gates and quantum circuits.

The barrier acts as a directive for circuit compilation to separate pieces of a circuit so that any optimizations or re-writes are constrained to only act between barriers (and if there are no barriers they act on the whole circuit).
This only comes into play when using the `transpile` or `execute` functions in Qiskit (`execute` includes a transpile step).

Below is an example, and you can find more examples in these Qiskit tutorial notebooks:

- [Quantum circuit properties](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/40af3da7aa86ce190d04f147daf46fbc893a1966/qiskit/fundamentals/4_quantum_circuit_properties.ipynb)
- [Using the transpiler](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/stable/0.15.x/qiskit/fundamentals/5_using_the_transpiler.ipynb)

**Example**

If a circuit has several 1-qubit gates in a row acting on the same qubit these can be combined into a single 1-qubit gate. If you explicitly want to prevent this sort of behaviour you can place a barrier between them.

Create a 1-qubit circuit with several gates

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, transpile

qr = QuantumRegister(1)
circuit1 = QuantumCircuit(qr)
circuit1.u1(0.2, qr[0])
circuit1.u2(0.1,0.2, qr[0])
circuit1.u3(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, qr[0])
circuit1.draw()
```

This circuit is

```
         ┌─────────┐┌─────────────┐┌─────────────────┐
q0_0: |0>┤ U1(0.2) ├┤ U2(0.1,0.2) ├┤ U3(0.1,0.2,0.3) ├
         └─────────┘└─────────────┘└─────────────────┘
```

If we transpile it, these gates are combined using the default settings

```
circuit1t = transpile(circuit1)
circuit1t.draw()
```

The returned circuit is

```
         ┌───────────────────────────┐
q0_0: |0>┤ U3(1.6629,0.6018,0.43905) ├
         └───────────────────────────┘
```

Now if we want to avoid the gates being combined we could add barriers:

```
qr = QuantumRegister(1)
circuit2 = QuantumCircuit(qr)
circuit2.u1(0.2, qr[0])
circuit2.barrier(qr)
circuit2.u2(0.1,0.2, qr[0])
circuit2.barrier(qr)
circuit2.u3(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, qr[0])
circuit2.draw()

         ┌─────────┐ ░ ┌─────────────┐ ░ ┌─────────────────┐
q1_0: |0>┤ U1(0.2) ├─░─┤ U2(0.1,0.2) ├─░─┤ U3(0.1,0.2,0.3) ├
         └─────────┘ ░ └─────────────┘ ░ └─────────────────┘
```

In this case transpiling wont change the circuit:

```
circuit2t = transpile(circuit2)
circuit2t.draw()
         ┌─────────┐ ░ ┌─────────────┐ ░ ┌─────────────────┐
q1_0: |0>┤ U1(0.2) ├─░─┤ U2(0.1,0.2) ├─░─┤ U3(0.1,0.2,0.3) ├
         └─────────┘ ░ └─────────────┘ ░ └─────────────────┘
```