# Implementing block of gates at different times in a same qiskit program

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I am implementing an Ising chain over 8 qubits. It involves pair-wise CNOT between all the qubits. In the first time step, I am doing CNOTs between qubits  0 and 1, 2 and 3, 4 and 5, and 6 and 7. In the second time step, I would do CNOTs between qubits 1 and 2, 3 and 4, and 5 and 6. I have written the code as follows:

```
# Block A for the first time step
qp.cx(q0,q1)
qp.cx(q2,q3)
qp.cx(q4,q5)
qp.cx(q6,q7) 

# Block B for the second time step
qp.cx(q1,q2)
qp.cx(q3,q4)
qp.cx(q5,q6)
```

I would like the gates in Block A to be applied simultaneously. Then, in the next step, gates in Block B should be applied simultaneously. How to convey to the compiler that I do not want the above written code to be compiled sequentially, rather I want it to be applied block-wise.

Comment: Why does not suit [barrier](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8371/12416) between the blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to put a barrier between your two blocks? You can do this by writing this `qp.barrier()` right after your first block, then Qiskit will transpile separately the two blocks. Is this what you were searching for?

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful.

Comment: @SHASHANKRANU happy to see so, could you maybe accept the answer? Thanks :)