# Circuit Construction using IBM Quantum Composer

Tags: ibm-q-experience, circuit-construction

I am trying to create the following circuit in IBM Quantum Composer but I cannot add the last H gate correctly. It falls in the wrong place. Why?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent in the sense that they implement the same unitary.

But if you want to keep the alignment you can insert a barrier:
[image]

Note however that if you plan to run your circuits on actual quantum computer, in general barriers may affect the process of transpilation and execution. See [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8371/9474) for details.

---

**Update**

In the new version of IBM Quantum Composer (now in beta) you can use *freeform* alignment to place gates anywhere in the composer:

[image]